# $A_1\cdots A_s=0$, prove $\sum_{i=1}^s \operatorname{rank}(A_i) \leq (s-1)n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A_1,\ldots,A_s$ are $n\times n$ matrices which satisfy $A_1\cdots A_s=0$

Want to prove

$$\sum_{i=1}^s \operatorname{rank}(A_i) \leq (s-1)n$$

I have no idea how to add up the ranks of matrices, so I didn't succeed by induction. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think the rank of the product of two matrices is he minimum of the two ranks. But I’m not sure.

Comment: That's not true. Consider [1 0; 0 0] multiplies [0 0; 0 1]. That gives 0!

Comment: The first comment is almost correct. The rank of $AB$ is **bounded above by** (but not necessarily equal to) the minimum of the ranks of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for s=2,it is clear.
If $s>2$,you can show this by prove
$rank(AB)+n≥rank(A)+rankB.$ you can prove this by elementary transformation for a matrix $[AB,0;0,I]$.then by induction,you can get the result.